# For my Quicksort algorithm how can I make it so that it sorts Strings and objects as well?

Tags: javascript, quicksort

My Quicksort is working perfectly and the code is here:

https://gist.github.com/RoloRobot/b2e15af9ab0d8c1bdbdd

What I want to do is make it sort not only numbers, but strings and objects as well. How would I go about doing that? Any help would be appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 3):

You could create a different `compare` function that you'd give to your quickSort

```
// numbers or strings
quickSort(array, left, right, (a, b) => a < b)

// custom objects comparison (by foo key)
quickSort(array, left, right, (a, b) => a.foo < b.foo)
```

And if you don't want to set them manually you can auto detect the types:

```
if (typeof item === 'string') { compare = compareStrings; }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this. I am going to be having 3 buttons, one for numbers, one for strings and one for objects. I just don't get how the above would accommodate the quickSort I already have for strings

Comment: Everytime you do a comparison, for instance `if(array[i] < pivotValue)`, use a comparison function instead `if (compare(array[i], pivotValue))`. This compare function will be different depending on what you compare